# Fixed header and footer moving on menu open

Tags: angularjs, html, css, semantic-ui

I'm having an issue in this Angular app where my footer and header (on mobile only) jump down 105px when opening the sidebar menu. The app is hosted [here](https://slackerchat.firebaseapp.com/#/channels/-JrdsDxNsh8ZG5HEubTW/messages), and you can see what happens when opened on mobile.  I can't reproduce it in Chrome on the desktop, however.

Please use these credentials and click any channel, and then pull out the sidebar menu to see the issue:

username: **test@test.com**
password: **test**

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slackchat</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='bower_components/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.css' />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900,700,300,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="slackerchat">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
  <div class="ui right vertical inverted labeled icon sidebar menu" id="sidebar">
      <a class="item" href="#/">
        <i class="home icon"></i>
        Home
      </a>
      <a class="item" href="#/login">
        <i class="sign in icon large"></i>
        Sign in
      </a>
      <a class="item" href="#/register">
        <i class="add user icon"></i>
        Register
      </a>
      <a class="item" ng-click="logout()">
        <i class="sign out icon large"></i>
        Sign out
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="pusher">




  <div class="ui padded grid">
  <div class="sixteen wide column row button raised" id="header-desktop">
      <div class="three wide column" id="logo-column">
        <a href="#/home"><img class="ui medium image left floated" id="logo-home" src="images/logo.svg" alt="slackerchat"></a>
        <a href="#/home"><img class="ui medium image left floated" id="logo-hash" src="images/logo-hash.svg" alt="slackerchat"></a>
        <div class="item" id="channel-dropdown">
          <div class="ui top right pointing dropdown">
            <div class="header">
              <h1 style="color:black;">{{ messagesCtrl.channelName }}</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
              <div class="item"><i class="user icon"></i><a href="#">Profile</a></div>
              <div class="item"><i class="users icon"></i><a href="#">Followers</a></div>
              <div class="item"><i class="unhide icon"></i><a href="#">Following</a></div>
              <div class="item"><i class="setting icon"></i><a href="#/Settings">Settings</a></div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="thirteen wide column" id="menu-container">
          <div class="ui list">
              <div class="ui large icon toggle button right floated">
                  <i class="content icon big"></i>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>-->
    </div>
  </div>


  <ui-view></ui-view>



  </div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-md5/angular-md5.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="auth/auth.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="auth/auth.service.js"></script>
    <script src="users/users.service.js"></script>
    <script src="users/profile.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="channels/channels.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="channels/channels.service.js"></script>
    <script src="channels/messages.service.js"></script>
    <script src="channels/messages.controller.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- SEMANTIC MODAL DROPDOWN -->
  <script>
    $('.dropdown').dropdown({
        // you can use any ui transition
        transition: 'drop'
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    $('.right.sidebar').first()
      .sidebar('setting', 'transition', 'uncover')
      .sidebar('attach events', '.toggle.button')
      .sidebar('attach events', '.menu .item')
    ;
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

messages.html

```
<div class="ui padded grid">
  <div class="sixteen wide column row button raised" id="header-mobile">
      <div class="ten wide column" id="remove-padding-left">
        <a href="#/home"><img class="ui medium image left floated" id="logo-hash" src="images/logo-hash.svg" alt="slackerchat"></a>
        <div class="item" id="channel-dropdown">
          <div class="ui dropdown">
            <div class="header">
              <h1>{{ messagesCtrl.channelName }} <i class="caret down icon"></i></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
              <div class="header">
                <p>Search Channels</p>
              </div>
              <div class="ui fluid left icon input">
                <i class="search icon"></i>
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
              </div>
              <div class="header">
                <p>Available Channels</p>
              </div>
              <div class="item" ng-repeat="channel in channelsCtrl.channels">
                  <a ui-sref="channels.messages({channelId: channel.$id})" ui-sref-active="selected"><img class="ui image left floated" id="hash" src="images/hash.svg" alt="hashtag">{{ channel.name }}</a>
              </div>  
              <div class="item" id="create-channel"><a ui-sref="channels.create"><i class="plus icon"></i>create a new channel</a></div>                       
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="six wide column" id="menu-container">
          <div class="ui list">
              <!-- SIDEBAR -->
              <div class="ui large icon toggle button right floated">
                  <i class="content icon big"></i>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>




<div class="header" id="messages-channel-active">
  <h1>{{ messagesCtrl.channelName }}</h1>
</div>

<div class="message-wrap" ng-repeat="message in messagesCtrl.messages">
  <img class="user-pic" ng-src="{{ channelsCtrl.getGravatar(message.uid) }}" />
  <div class="message-info">
    <div class="user-name">
      {{ channelsCtrl.getDisplayName(message.uid) }}
      <span class="timestamp">{{ message.timestamp | date:'short' }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
     {{ message.body }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ui comments">
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="avatar-container">
      <a class="avatar">
        <img src="/images/avatar/elliot.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui card">
    <div class="content">
        <i class="right floated like icon"></i>
        <i class="right floated star icon"></i>
        <a class="author">toddler</a>
        <div class="metadata">
          <div class="date">11:53am</div>
          <div class="right floated rating">
            <i class="star icon"></i>
            5 Faves
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          Hey, have you seen my latest video at <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kILY0L9oTc0" target="_blank">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kILY0L9oTc0?</a>
        </div>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kILY0L9oTc0" target="_blank">
            <img src="/images/surfing.jpg">
          </a>
        <div class="content">
          <a class="header" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kILY0L9oTc0" target="_blank">Surfing in Hawaii</a>
          <div class="meta">
            <a>Last Watched 1 minute ago</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comment">
    <div class="avatar-container">
      <a class="avatar">
        <img src="/images/avatar/helen.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui card">
    <div class="content">
        <i class="right floated like icon"></i>
        <i class="right floated star icon"></i>
        <a class="author">Miss Priss</a>
        <div class="metadata">
          <div class="date">11:55am</div>
          <div class="right floated rating">
            <i class="star icon"></i>
            2 Faves
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          No, actually I haven't.  But I'm checking it out now!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comment">
    <div class="avatar-container">
      <a class="avatar">
        <img src="/images/avatar/joe.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui card">
    <div class="content">
        <i class="right floated like icon"></i>
        <i class="right floated star icon"></i>
        <a class="author">Big Boba</a>
        <div class="metadata">
          <div class="date">11:57am</div>
          <div class="right floated rating">
            <i class="star icon"></i>
            3 Faves
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          Wow, it looks like you really bit the dust on that last wave.  I'd love to learn, but I'll stick to the small waves here in Newport Beach.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="form-wrapper">
  <form class="message-form" ng-submit="messagesCtrl.sendMessage()">
    <div class="huge ui fluid left icon input">
      <input type="text" id="input-message" ng-model="messagesCtrl.message" placeholder="Write a message..." class="form-control">
      <button class="huge ui circular icon button" id="search-button-circle" type="submit">
        <i class="white send icon"></i>
      </button>
      <i class="write icon"></i>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>


<!-- SEMANTIC MODAL DROPDOWN -->
  <script>
    $('.dropdown').dropdown({
        // you can use any ui transition
        transition: 'drop'
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    $('.right.sidebar').first()
      .sidebar('setting', 'transition', 'uncover')
      .sidebar('attach events', '.toggle.button')
      .sidebar('attach events', '.menu .item')
    ;
  </script>
```

main.css

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  background: #eef2f5;
}

*:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
}

a, span, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, body {font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif !important;}

.page-wrapper {
  max-width:550px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding:15px;
}

.page-wrapper .logo-img {
  margin-top:-10px;
}


.main {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.sidebar {
  display:inline-block;
  width:20%;
  vertical-align: top;
  height:100%;
  background:#393f4d;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  float:left;
  min-height: 1600px;
}

.sidebar .slack-name {
  background:#313743;
  padding:15px 0px 15px 15px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #2c313c;
}

.sidebar .slack-name h2{
  color:#fff;
  font-size:22px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}

.sidebar .room-list {
  margin-top:20px;
  background:#4d394b;
}

.sidebar .room-list .room a{
  display:block;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  padding:3px 0px 3px 15px;
  width:90%;
  font-weight:300;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.sidebar .room-list .room a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  background:#3E313C;
}

.sidebar .room-list .room a.selected{
  background:#4c9689;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.sidebar .room-list .room.create {
  font-style: italic;
}

.sidebar .room-list .list-head {
  margin-top:10px;
  color: #a5adbe;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sidebar .my-info {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  padding:20px 15px;
  background:#313743;
  width:20%;
  border-top: 3px solid #2c313c;
}

.sidebar .my-info .user-pic {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width:44px;
  height:44px;
  border-radius:4px;
}

.sidebar .my-info .user-info {
  padding-left:5px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.sidebar .my-info .user-info .user-name {
  color:#fff;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.sidebar .my-info .user-info .options {
  color:#999;
  font-size:12px;
}

.sidebar .my-info .user-info .options a{
  color:#999;
  font-size:12px;
}

.sidebar .presence {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ab9ba9;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sidebar .presence.online {
  background: #99d04a;
}

.message-pane {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height:100%;
  width:80%;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eef2f5 !important;
  float: right;
  min-height: 1600px;
}

.message-pane .header {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.message-pane .header h1 {
  padding: 17px 0 0 0;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  font-size:24px;
  color:#393f4d;
  font-weight:900;
}

.message-pane .message-form {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eef2f5;
  padding: 17px 0px 7px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.26);
  z-index: 100;
  }

.message-pane .message-wrap {
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 20px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0 1.3px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  padding: 15px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: .2rem;
}

.message-pane .message-wrap .user-pic {
  width:36px;
  height:36px;
  border-radius:4px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.message-pane .message-wrap .message-info {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left:5px;
}

.message-pane .message-wrap .message-info .user-name {
  color:#555459;
  font-weight:900;
}

.message-pane .message-wrap .message-info .user-name span{
  color:#ccc;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size:10px;
}
.ui.comments .comment a.author {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.avatar-container {
  width: 8%;
}

/*  ------------SEMANTIC FONTS------------ */
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Icons';
 src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.2/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.eot");
 src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.2/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.2/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff2") format('woff'), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.2/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff") format('woff'), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.2/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.ttf") format('truetype'), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.2/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.svg#icons") format('svg');
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 text-decoration: inherit;
 text-transform: none;
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

/* -------------MATERIAL DESIGN CUSTOM STYLES---------------  */
.button.raised {
      transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
      transition-delay: 0.2s;
      box-shadow: 4px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    }

/* -----------HEADER-------------- */
#header-desktop {
  position: fixed !important;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f8f9fb;
  height: 65px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.page-wrapper, .main {
  position: relative;
  top: 65px;
}
#logo-home, #logo-hash {
  padding-top: 0em;
  max-width: 180px;
  max-height: 160px;
}
#logo-hash {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#channel-dropdown {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#logo-column {
  height: 50px;
}

/* ----------SIDEBAR----------- */
.channel {
  padding: 2px 0px;
}
.channel.ng-scope a {
  color: #a5adbe;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.channel.create a {
  color: #a5adbe;
}
.channel-list {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
.list-head {
  color: #a5adbe;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
a.ng-binding.selected {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.channel.create {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 3px solid #2c313c;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
/* --------------MESSAGE---------------- */
input#input-message, input[type="text"] {
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
#search-button-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  background-color: #684d5e;
  margin: 0 15px 7px 15px;
  z-index: 998;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.ui.card {
  width: 92%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.ui.comments .comment .avatar img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.ui.comments {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.ui.comments img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 8px 0 12px 0;
}

/* -------------DROPDOWN--------------- */
.item a {
  color: #684d5e;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
.item a:hover {
  color: #684d5e;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.item a.selected {
  color: #684d5e;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
#hash {
  max-width: 18px;
  max-height: 18px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
.menu {
  width: 110%;
}
i.small.chevron.down.icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-bottom: 1.3em;
}
i.white.send.icon:before {
  margin-left: -5px;
}
.ui.circular.button > .icon {
  width: 1em;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  height: 1em;
}
#create-channel {
  background: #F3F3F3;
}
#create-channel:hover {
  background: #393f4d;
}
#create-channel a {
  color: #684d5e;
}
#create-channel a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}
body.pushable > .pusher {
  /*background: #393f4d !important;*/
}
#header-mobile {display: none;}
#messages-channel-active {margin-left: 18px;}


/* --------------SIDE POPOUT MENU------------------- */
.ui.icon.toggle.button.right.floated {
    background: none;
    padding-top: .1em;
    color: #684d5e !important;
  }
  .ui.icon.toggle.button.right.floated:hover, .ui.icon.toggle.button.right.floated:active {
    color: #393f4d !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
  .pushable > .pusher {
    overflow: visible;
  }

/* --------------MEDIA QUERIES------------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1370px) {
  .ui.card {
    width: 90%;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  .ui.card {
    width: 89%;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #header-desktop, #logo-column {
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
  .message-pane, .form-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .message-pane .message-wrap {
    margin: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  }
  #logo-hash {
      visibility: visible;
      max-width: 45px;
      max-height: 45px;
      padding-top: 3px;
  }
  #logo-home {
    display: none;
  }
  #channel-dropdown {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #header-mobile {
      position: fixed !important;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 6px 0 0 0;
      height: 60px;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background: #f8f9fb;
      z-index: 100;
  }
  .button.raised {
      transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
      transition-delay: 0.2s;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  #messages-channel-active {display: none;}
  .main {
    top: 60px;
  }
  .ui.dropdown > .menu {
    width: 145%;
  }
  .header p {margin-left: 5px;}
  .ui.icon.toggle.button.right.floated {
    padding-top: .5em;
  }
  .message-pane .header h1 {
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .ui.card {
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is what it looks like when you open the popout menu.  Check out the header and footer shifting down:

http://toddlerwilliams.com/images/shifting-header.png

Answer (score 1):

You should put your main scrollable content within `<md-content></md-content>` and perhaps add `md-scroll-y` as an attribute to prevent x scrolling. For your app you'd want to surround your chat area in this so only it scrolls instead of the whole page scrolling.

Here is a demo of using `md-content`
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.content

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I'd rather not add any more CSS or JS dependencies at this point.

Comment: @ToddWilliams You already use angular-material. `md-content` is just a fancy way to do `overflow: auto;` and it's included in angular-material.

Comment: Thanks, and I'll give this a go for keeping the sidebar from scrolling.  I should have been clearer, though, because the issue I'm having is being caused by the popout menu on the right in mobile.  For this popout menu, I would like to continue to use the included Semantic-UI toolbar that I'm implementing, however.  

You can see the "pusher" class in index.html.  That is what is wrapping the entire page to push it out when the menu is activated.  It's a Semantic-UI class.